# Is Pythons random.randint statistically random?

Tags: python, random, statistics, probability

So I'm testing an  calculating the probabilities of certain dice rolls, for a game.
The base case if that rolling one 10sided die.

I did a million samples of this, and ended up with the following proportions:

```
Result
0       0.000000000000000%
1       10.038789961210000%
2       10.043589956410000%
3       9.994890005110000%
4       10.025289974710000%
5       9.948090051909950%
6       9.965590034409970%
7       9.990190009809990%
8       9.985490014509990%
9       9.980390019609980%
10      10.027589972410000%
```

These should of course all be 10%.
There is a standard deviation of  0.0323207% in these results.
that, to me, seems rather high.
Is it just coincidence?
As I understand it the random module accesses proper pseudo-random numbers.
Ie ones from a method that pass the statistical tests to be random.
Or are these pseudo-pseudo-random number generators

Should I be using cryptographic pseudo-random number generators?
I'm fairly sure I don't need a *true* random number generator (see http://www.random.org/, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator).

I am currently regenerating all my results with 1 billion samples, 
(cos why not, I have a crunchy server at my disposal, and some sleep to do)

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: my code  is basically just: `random.randint(1, 10)`
Their isn't much more to it, (there are some other things that come into effect only when the number of dice rolled is greater than 1)

Comment: Do these results predict what happens on a second run of the same code?

Comment: Steven: They *should* (at least to an extent, though i'm now learning why they sholdn't) since I am trying to average our the randomness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martijn's answer is a pretty succinct review of the random number generators that Python has access to.

If you want to check out the properties of the generated pseudo-random data, download `random.zip` from http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/, and run it on a big sample of random data. Especially the χ² (chi squared) test is very sensitive to randomness. For a sequence to be really random, the percentage from the χ² test should be between 10% and 90%.

For a game I'd guess that the Mersenne Twister that Python uses internally should be sufficiently random (unless you're building an online casino :-).

If you want *pure* randomness, and if you are using Linux, you can read from `/dev/random`. This only produces random data from the kernel's entropy pool (which is gathered from the unpredictable times that interrupts arrive), so it will block if you exhaust it. This entropy is used to initialize (seed) the PRNG used by `/dev/urandom`. On FreeBSD, the PRNG that supplies data for `/dev/random` uses the Yarrow algorithm, which is generally regarded as being cryptographically secure.

**Edit:** I ran some tests on bytes from `random.randint`. First creating a million random bytes:

```
import random
ba = bytearray([random.randint(0,255) for n in xrange(1000000)])
with open('randint.dat', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(ba)
```

Then I ran the `ent` program from [Fourmilab](http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/) on it:

```
Entropy = 7.999840 bits per byte.

Optimum compression would reduce the size
of this 1000000 byte file by 0 percent.

Chi square distribution for 1000000 samples is 221.87, and randomly
would exceed this value 93.40 percent of the times.

Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 127.5136 (127.5 = random).
Monte Carlo value for Pi is 3.139644559 (error 0.06 percent).
Serial correlation coefficient is -0.000931 (totally uncorrelated = 0.0).
```

Now for the χ² test, the further you get from 50%, the more suspect the data is. If one is very fussy, values <10% or >90% are deemed unacceptable. John Walker, author of `ent` calls this value "almost suspect".

As a contrast, here is the same analysis of 10 MiB from FreeBSD's Yarrow prng that I ran earlier:

```
Entropy = 7.999982 bits per byte.

Optimum compression would reduce the size
of this 10485760 byte file by 0 percent.

Chi square distribution for 10485760 samples is 259.03, and randomly
would exceed this value 41.80 percent of the times.

Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 127.5116 (127.5 = random).
Monte Carlo value for Pi is 3.139877754 (error 0.05 percent).
Serial correlation coefficient is -0.000296 (totally uncorrelated = 0.0).
```

While there seems not much difference in the other data, the χ² precentage is *much* closer to 50%.

Comment: FYI: This is for the statistical t5esting, of a game.
Not a game being played, but for testing a game being designed.
the single die roll is a base case

Comment: For answering the core of your question, which I would paraphrase as "are these numbers to be expected from a random number generator" the χ² test is the way to go because it is very sensitive to non-randomness.

Answer (score 17):

From the [`random` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html):

> Almost all module functions depend on the basic function random(), which generates a random float uniformly in the semi-open range [0.0, 1.0). Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator. It produces 53-bit precision floats and has a period of 2**19937-1. The underlying implementation in C is both fast and threadsafe. The Mersenne Twister is one of the most extensively tested random number generators in existence. However, being completely deterministic, it is not suitable for all purposes, and is completely unsuitable for cryptographic purposes.

From the [Wikipedia article on the Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister):

> It provides for fast generation of very high-quality pseudorandom numbers, having been designed specifically to rectify many of the flaws found in older algorithms.

If you have an OS-specific randomness source, available through [`os.urandom()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.urandom), then you can use the [`random.SystemRandom()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) class instead. Most of the `random` module functions are available as methods on that class. It perhaps would be more suitable for cryptographic purposes, quoting the docs again:

> The returned data should be unpredictable enough for cryptographic applications, though its exact quality depends on the OS implementation.

Python 3.6 adds a [`secrets` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/secrets.html) with convenience methods to produce random data suitable for cryptographic purposes:

> The `secrets` module is used for generating cryptographically strong random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.
>
> In particularly, `secrets` should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the `random` module, which is designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.

Answer (score 4):

I reran the OP's exercise with one billion iterations:

```
from collections import Counter
import random
n = 1000000000
c = Counter(random.randint(1, 10) for _ in xrange(n))
for i in range(1,11):
    print '%2s  %02.10f%%' % (i, c[i] * 100.0 / n)
```

Here's the (reformatted) result:

```
 1     9.9996500000%
 2    10.0011089000%
 3    10.0008568000%
 4    10.0007495000%
 5     9.9999089000%
 6     9.9985344000%
 7     9.9994913000%
 8     9.9997877000%
 9    10.0010818000%
10     9.9988307000%
```

See the other answers to this question for their excellent analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is statistically random for all practical purposes. The random variation you saw is perfectly normal. In fact it would be a poor rng if it didn't have variation like that.

Since the period of the prng is 2**19937-1, you would need to generate more numbers than there are atoms in the universe before you see a nonrandom distribution. Note that if you generate 623 dimensional vectors, it becomes non random much sooner.

Comment: I don't see how " poor rng if it didn't have variation like that."
Can you clarify?
I would expect very little variation from 10% when averaging over 1 million test

Comment: @Oxinabox You are confusing randomness with even distribution. [It's not that easy.](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/)

Comment: @Oxinabox: You'd have to run a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test on your random data and compare the output of that to the p-value of a χ² distribution with 9 degrees of freedom to be able to make the call wether or not the numbers you got were non-random. See the "Examples" section in the linked Wikipedia article. This is essentially what the `ent` sorftware that I pointed to in my answer does for random bytes (255 degrees of freedom).

Answer (score 2):

These results are very close to what you'd expect, and there's a simple calculation you can do to check that. If you roll 1,000,000 D10s and count the number of 1s (say) the mean of that random variable is 100,000 (number of trials * probability of success) and the variance is 90,000 (number of trials * probability of success * probability of failure), so the standard deviation is sqrt(90,000)=300. So you should expect to get something about 300 away from 100,000, i.e. 10% +/- 0.03%.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed normal for random numbers to come up imperfectly distributed with a good PRNG.  However, the more numbers you generate, the less you should see that.

BTW, I'm getting a standard deviation of 0.03066, which is slightly lower than what you gave.