# Randint doesn't always follow uniform distribution

Tags: python, random

I was playing around with the random library in Python to simulate a project I work and I found myself in a very strange position.

Let's say that we have the following code in Python:

```
from random import randint
import seaborn as sns

a = []
for i in range(1000000):
    a.append(randint(1,150))

sns.distplot(a)
```

The plot follows a “discrete uniform” distribution as it should.

[image: Range betwee 1 and 150]

However, when I change the range from 1 to 110, the plot has several peaks.

```
from random import randint
import seaborn as sns

a = []
for i in range(1000000):
    a.append(randint(1,110))

sns.distplot(a)
```

[image: Range from 1 to 110]

My impression is that the peaks are on 0,10,20,30,... but I am not able to explain it.

**Edit:** The question was not similar with the proposed one as duplicate since the problem in my case was the seaborn library and the way I visualised the data.

**Edit 2:** Following the suggestions on the answers, I tried to verify it by changing the seaborn library. Instead, using matplotlib both graphs were the same

```
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = []
for i in range(1000000):
    a.append(randint(1,110))

plt.hist(a)
```

[image: From matplotlib]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Pythons random.randint statistically random?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164280/is-pythons-random-randint-statistically-random)

Comment: You should be able to see from your superimposed kernel density plot that the peaks are not real.

Comment: And now you can solve this puzzle: https://ericlippert.com/2012/02/24/a-simple-puzzle/

Comment: @EricLippert Now if only we could get the .NET team to fix the equivalent bug in `System.Random`...

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your grapher, `seaborn`, not in `randint()`.

There are 50 bins in your `seaborn` distribution diagram, according to my count. It seems that seaborn is actually binning your returned `randint()` values in those bins, and there is no way to get an even spread of 110 values into 50 bins. Therefore you get those peaks where three values get put into a bin rather than the usual two values for the other bins. The values of your peaks confirm this: they are 50% higher than the other bars, as expected for 3 binned values rather than for 2.

Another way for you to check this is to force `seaborn` to use 55 bins for these 110 values (or perhaps 10 bins or some other divisor of 110). If you still get the peaks, then you should worry about `randint()`.

Comment: When something is so obvious but you are just blind! Makes 100% sense now. Thank you for your answer. Will accept it as soon as the time limit passes :)

Comment: We all have those moments of overlooking the obvious: I certainly do! And you are welcome.

Answer (score 21):

To add to @RoryDaulton 's excellent answer, I ran `randint(1:110)`, generating a frequency count and the converting it to an R-vector of counts like this:

```
hits = {i:0 for i in range(1,111)}
for i in range(1000000): hits[randint(1,110)] += 1
hits = [hits[i] for i in range(1,111)]
s = 'c('+','.join(str(x) for x in hits)+')'
print(s)

c(9123,9067,9124,8898,9193,9077,9155,9042,9112,9015,8949,9139,9064,9152,8848,9167,9077,9122,9025,9159,9109,9015,9265,9026,9115,9169,9110,9364,9042,9238,9079,9032,9134,9186,9085,9196,9217,9195,9027,9003,9190,9159,9006,9069,9222,9205,8952,9106,9041,9019,8999,9085,9054,9119,9114,9085,9123,8951,9023,9292,8900,9064,9046,9054,9034,9088,9002,8780,9098,9157,9130,9084,9097,8990,9194,9019,9046,9087,9100,9017,9203,9182,9165,9113,9041,9138,9162,9024,9133,9159,9197,9168,9105,9146,8991,9045,9155,8986,9091,9000,9077,9117,9134,9143,9067,9168,9047,9166,9017,8944)
```

I then pasted this to an R-console, reconstructed the observations and used R's `hist()` on the result, obtaining this histogram (with superimposed density curve):

[image]

As you can see, this confirms that the problem you observed isn't traceable to `randint` but is an artifact of `sns.displot()`.

Comment: I count 22 bars in that histogram, and of course 22 is a divisor of 110. Thanks for confirming and elaborating on part of my answer.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Good observation about 22. I tweaked the histogram so that now it is a probability histogram with a superimposed density, hence matching more closely what OP was doing.

Comment: You can get a similar effect to the seaborn plot with `hist(x,breaks=seq(0,110,by=2.2))`. Curiously, asking for 50 bins directly doesn't give the effect.