# How do you take randomness into account when finding the complexity of a function?

Tags: python, time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I've been trying to understand complexities, but all the online material has left me confused. Especially the part where they create actual mathematical functions. I have a for loop and a while loop. My confusion arises from the while loop. I know the complexity of the for loop is O(n), but the while loop is based on randomness. A random number if picked, and if this number is not in the list, it is added and the while loop broken. But my confusion arises here, the while loop may run in the worst case (in my thoughts) for an m number of times, until it is done. So I was thinking the complexity would then be O(n*m)?

I'm just really lost, and need some help.

Comment: Complexity is not about the absolute number of operations, is about the growth ratio. If you have a list and make it double in size, will your algorithm require twice as much steps? then is a linear growth O(n). Will doubling the size make it run n times more? then is O(n^2), etc...

Comment: Please add the code. It's not clear what the list is and how the random number is chosen. But FWIW, that sounds like *O(inf)*, for example if it's possible that the list contains all the possible numbers, or that a number not in the list is never chosen.

Comment: Added code. I'm trying to keep track of the steps that are taken, and how they can correlate to the input. I should've mentioned I'm trying to find the Big O notation complexity

Comment: OK, so it's not *O(inf)*. I'm not quite sure what it actually is though -- maybe *O(n^2)* or *O(n^3)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically worst-case complexity is `O(inf)`: `random.randint` if we consider it real random generator ([it isn't, of course](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164280/is-pythons-random-randint-statistically-random)) can produce arbitrary long sequence with equal elements. However, we can estimate "average-case" complexity. It isn't the real average-case complexity (best, worst and average cases must be defined by input, not randomly), but it can show how many iterations program will do, if we run it for fixed `n` multiple times and take average of results.

Let's note that the list works as set here (you never add repeated number), so I'd stick with `not in set` comparison instead which is `O(1)` (while `not in list` is `O(i)`) to remove that complexity source and simplify things a bit: now count of iterations and complexity can be estimated with same big O limits. Single *trial* here is choosing from uniform integer distribution on `[1; n]`. *Success* is choosing number that is not in the list yet.

Then what's expected value of number of trials before getting item that is not in the set? Set size before each step is `i` in your code. We can pick any of `n-i` numbers. Thus probability of success is `p_i = (n-i)/n` (as the distribution is uniform). Every outer iteration is an example of geometrical distribution: count of trials before first success. So estimated count of `while` iterations is `n_i = 1 / p_i = n / (n-i)`. To get final complexity we should sum this counts for each `for` iteration: `sum(n_i for i in range(n))`. This is obviously equal to `n * Harmonic(n)`, where `Harmonic(n)` is n-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) (sum of first `n` reciprocals to natural numbers). `Harmonic(n) ~ O(log n)`, thus "average-case" complexity  of this code is `O(n log n)`.

For list it will be `sum(i*n / (n-i) for i in range(n)) ~ O(n^2 log(n))` (proof of this equality will be a little longer).

Comment: Nice, this is the same conclusion I came to but couldn't put into words. Just to be clear though, you're considering `x not in set` (*O(1)*) instead of `x not in list` (*O(n)*), right? It'd help to [edit] and make that explicit. Also, I was thinking, instead of `rand_num not in <set>`, would it be equivalent but simpler to consider `rand_num != i`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm considering `not in set` to eliminate other complexity sources and stick to iterations count. For `not in list` complexity will be higher (`O(n^2 log n)` probably, but not sure here). `rand_num != i` will be completely different story (with probability of success  `1 - 1/n`), but `rand_num >= i` should result in same complexity.

Comment: UPD: yes, it'll be `O(n^2 log n)` for list, checked this limit with Wolfram Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

Big 'O' notation is used for worst case scenarios only.
figure out what could be he worst case for given loop.
make a function in 'n' , and take highest power of 'n' and ignore constant if any, you will get time complexity.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, in my case. I believe the randomness is technically the worst case. As the while loop could go on for a very long time, especially as the number increase. My trouble is just translating this to the big O notation